# How to get 'select' value and put into 'input' value?

Tags: php

I have a for with a select dropdown option. I want to get the value that is selected and put it into a hidden input value. I'm trying this at the minute -

```
echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
echo"<select name='qty'>
             <option value=1>1</option>
             <option value=2>2</option>
             <option value=3>3</option>
             <option value=4>4</option>
             <option value=5>5</option>
             <option value=6>6</option>
             <option value=7>7</option>
             <option value=8>8</option>
             <option value=9>9</option>
             <option value=10>10</option>
             </select>";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_qty" value="'.$_GET['qty'].'" />';
echo"</form>;
```

When I submit this to cart-update.php it tells me that qty is an undefined index on the hidden input line.

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: It means 'qty' was not included in the URL to load the page. i.e. `yoursite.com/index.php?qty=42`

Comment: `$_GET` is only available after submitting the form.

Comment: Looking at the code, there doesn't seem to be any reason for the hidden field. Just add `selected` to the appropriate `option` tag using PHP. There are thousands of tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A few problems:
1. Your form is in POST method, and you are trying to get the value in "Get" method  ($_GET)
2. The value of $_GET will be available only after submitting the form.

You should use javascript to get the value. something like that:

```
<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
<select name='qty' onChange='document.getElementById("product_qty").value = this.value'>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=6>6</option>
    <option value=7>7</option>
    <option value=8>8</option>
    <option value=9>9</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="product_qty" name="product_qty" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use javascript or jQuery. Some sample jQuery code:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var val1 = $('select').val();
  $('your selector').val(val1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it did work but i ended up going with BioSP's answer below as it used less code. I dont know if this is better or not though. I appreciate your input!

Comment: @GlenR I know this is an old comment, but this answer is ***a lot*** better. Less code is not always better, especially when dealing with archaic inline event attributes such as `onchange` and `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Consider this instead:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($arr as $n){
  $selected = $n == $_POST['qty'] ? 'selected' : '';
  echo "<option value='$n' $selected>$n</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Undefined_variable answer:

```
/***************************/
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

/* selecy key from list , insert into field */ 

$('#select_start_key').change(function(){

var val1 = $('#select_start_key').val();

$('#start_key').val(val1);

/*reset the select to none*/
$('#select_start_key').val("");

});

});
```

View example :

https://jsfiddle.net/alinrzv/aj619Lbb/